# Communication between Chrome-app and a homepage with PostMessage

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app, postmessage

I need to be able to send postMessage from a Chrome App through a webview to the homepage and back.

I have established PostMessage from the Chrome App to the homepage, and the PostMessage is also catched by the homepage and a new one is send back, but this PostMessage reply is not caught by the Chrome App.

I can see that it is possible on the Chrome-App API.:

[The guest will be able to send replies to the embedder by posting message to event.source on the message event it receives.](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-ContentWindow-postMessage)

So the problem is that i cannot get the Chrome App to catch the reply from the homepage, even though i am using event.source.postMessage('', event.origin) the send the reply with. Is the window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, false); at the end of background.js wrong ?

I have include the my code below.:

**background.js** (where the Chrome app is initialized).:

```
  var myAppWin = null;
  var webview = null;

chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  // Center window on screen.
  var screenWidth = screen.availWidth/2;
  var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;

  var chromeWindow = chrome.app.window.create('webview-embed.html', {
    id: "helloWorldID",
    bounds: {
      width: screenWidth,
      height: screenHeight,
    }
  }, function(win) {

        myAppWin = win;
        myAppWin.contentWindow.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

          webview = myAppWin.contentWindow.document.getElementById('webview');

          try{
            webview.addEventListener("contentload", function () {

              console.log("webview content is now loaded");

              try{
                console.log("Trying to post message");
                webview.contentWindow.postMessage("Message from Chrome APP!", "*");
              }catch(error){
                console.log("postMessage error: " + error);
              }

            });
          }
          catch(err) {
            console.log("Webview error: " + err);
          }

        });
  });

  //Event listnener for the PostMessage reply    
  var messageHandler = function(event) {
    console.log("got message from page back: " + event.data);
  };
  window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, false);



});
```

**webview-embed.html** (html file with the webview tag).:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>webview</title>
</head>
<body style='margin:0;padding:0;' >
    <webview src="http://localhost" style="width:100%;height:100%;" id="webview" ></webview>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html** (the homepage on the web, that needs to catch the first PostMessage and sent a reply back to the Chrome-app).:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body >
    <div id="wrapper" >
        //body
    </div>

    //Used to catch messages from the Chrome App and reply back 
    var messageHandler = function(event) {
      console.log('Message received fom APP!');
      try{
        console.log(event);
        event.source.postMessage("Message from page", event.origin);
        console.log("Sent massage back to APP");
      }catch(error){
        console.log("Error on postMessage back to APP" + error);
      }

    };
    window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, false);

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't diagnosed the whole problem, but part of it may be that you are using global variables in your background.js to retain data, and that won't work in an event page, because it's unloaded and reloaded as needed. (Only the fact that certain event handlers were set is remembered, but not the handlers themselves.)

Comment: Do you need to send and receive the message from the background page? If you send the message from the app's main page, it should just work, i.e. sending it from the JavaScript of webview-embed.html

Comment: @lazyboy I would like to make a [notification](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications) when a event (incoming message) is happening on the webpage, do you know if it can be achieved in a different way ?

Comment: This could be one possibility if you own both the page and the extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the input. Found a solution!

I made a webview.js and loaded it in webview-embed.html

```
var messageHandler = function(event) {
  console.log("Got message from webpage back: " + event.data);
};

webview = document.getElementById('webview');
webview.addEventListener("contentload", function () {
  try{
    console.log("Trying to post message");
    webview.contentWindow.postMessage("Message from Chrome APP!", "*");
  }catch(error){
    console.log("postMessage error: " + error);
  }

});
window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, false);
```

Cleaned up my background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  // Center window on screen.
  var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
  var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;

  var chromeWindow = chrome.app.window.create('webview-embed.html', {
    id: "helloWorldID",
    bounds: {
      width: screenWidth,
      height: screenHeight,
    }
  });
});
```

and the index.html on the web.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body >
    <div id="wrapper" >
        //body
    </div>
    <script>
    var messageHandler = function(event) {

      console.log('Message received fom APP!');

      try {
        event.source.postMessage("Message from webpage", "*");
        console.log('message send back to get catched by webview');
      } catch(error) {
        console.log("Error on postMessage back to APP" + error);
      }

    };
    window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, false);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```