# Chrome App: Window interacting with another window's HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm coding an app which, in its main window's javascript code, creates a new window.

Mainwindow.js :

```
chrome.app.window.create('sample.html', {
        id: 'newwindow',
        'bounds': {
          'width': 200,
          'height': 200
        },
        'resizable' : false,
        'alwaysOnTop' : true,
        'frame': { type: "none" }
    }, function(createdWindow) {
    /*here*/
})
```

sample.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Chrome app</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style='background-image: url("img1.png"); height: 50px; width: 200px;'>
 </body>
</html>
```

The thing i'd like to do is to interact with sample.html code inside mainwindow.js, in order to change the path of the background image. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Have you looked through this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949427/communication-between-chrome-app-and-a-homepage-with-postmessage

Comment: @gui47 Well, I just did, and it didn't seem to be resolving my problem. Tell me if i'm wrong but he only has one window, with a webview inside, and i want to "talk" between his window and his webview content... The thing is that i have 2 windows generated by my Chrome app.